# Cannot access or assign login username variable - mysql - php

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I cannot find a way to access the username I used to log in with on my php web form.

I have had a look at these posts but I think my case varies slightly as they both declare the username variable at the top. I simply log in using a sql query.

Here is the login script

```php
<?php
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$password=$_POST['password']; 
session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","g7trj98o6fyr5","login");//mysqli("localhost","username of database","password of database","database name")
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `login_info` WHERE `uname`='$uname' && `password`='$password'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{
    echo "Login success";
    $_SESSION['log']=1;
    header("refresh:2;url=welcome.php");

}
else
{
    echo "please fill proper details";
    header("refresh:2;url=index.php");
}
?>
```

I'm expecting to be able to do a if check using the currently logged in user to differentiate them from all other users online.

I have this if check which should only put the edit button next to the user who is logged in.

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['uname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['clickrate'] . "</td>";
if($logedInUsername == $row['uname'])
    echo "<td>" . $row['yourword'] . "<a href='edityourword.php?edit=$row[yourword]'> edit</a></td>";
else
    echo "<td>" . $row['yourword'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

welcome.php (where the if statement is)

```php
<?php

function add_ant(&$connection)
{
    mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `login_info` SET `clickrate`=`clickrate`+'1' WHERE `uname`='rvbvakama' && `password`='pass'");
}

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['log']))
{

$_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['uname'];

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$logedInUsername');</script>";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","login"); //mysqli("localhost","username of database","password of database","database name")

if(array_key_exists('add',$_POST))
{
   add_ant($con);
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login_info");
if (!$result) 
{
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>username</th>
<th>clickrate</th>
<th>yourword</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['uname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['clickrate'] . "</td>";
if($logedInUsername == $_SESSION['uname'])
    echo "<td>" . $row['yourword'] . "<a href='edityourword.php?edit=$row[yourword]'> edit</a></td>";
else
    echo "<td>" . $row['yourword'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add ants</h1>
<button type='button' name="add">ADD</button> <br/> <br/>
<a href="index.php" >logout</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
else
{
    echo "please fill proper details";
    header("refresh:2;url=index.php");
}

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements. Also you should never save plaintext password in the DB.

Comment: @Dharman its just a fake pass, don't worry and sql injection will be fixed later, that was not my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in login.php after login success execute this
`$_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['uname'];`

in welcome.php execute this
`$logedInUsername = $_SESSION['uname'];`

Now the currently logged in username is stored in `$logedInUsername` for use in welcome.php, this is because SESSION is a global var in php and can be accessed from anywhere.

The while loop and if statement in it should now look like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['uname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['clickrate'] . "</td>";
if($row['uname'] == $logedInUsername)
    echo "<td>" . $row['yourword'] . "<a href='edityourword.php?edit=$row[yourword]'> edit</a></td>";
else
    echo "<td>" . $row['yourword'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not safe, but put:

```
<?php
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$password=$_POST['password']; 
session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","g7trj98o6fyr5","login");//mysqli("localhost","username of database","password of database","database name")
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `login_info` WHERE `uname`='$uname' && `password`='$password'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{
    echo "Login success";
    $_SESSION['log']=1;
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['uname'];
    header("refresh:2;url=welcome.php");

}
else
{
    echo "please fill proper details";
    header("refresh:2;url=index.php");
}
?>
```

and then check:

```
if($logedInUsername == $_SESSION['uname'])
...
```

also you need to set $logedInUsername to $row['uname'] in welcome.php
or check

```
if($row['uname'] == $_SESSION['uname'])
```

Comment: That is resulting in errors 
```Notice: Undefined index: uname in C:\xampp\htdocs\AntClicker\login\welcome.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: logedInUsername in C:\xampp\htdocs\AntClicker\login\welcome.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined variable: logedInUsername in C:\xampp\htdocs\AntClicker\login\welcome.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined variable: logedInUsername in C:\xampp\htdocs\AntClicker\login\welcome.php on line 42
```
I've added my welcome.php for more clarity

Comment: I think this enough information to go off, I'll post back in the morning when, hopefully, I figure it out.

Comment: okay, rubber duck, I figured it out as I was typing this. When you said "also you need to set $logedInUsername to $row['uname'] in welcome.php or check" I think that may be wrong as $row is not defined at that point in welcome.php.
What I needed to do was simply ```$logedInUsername = $_SESSION['uname'];```, I believe this works because in login.php we execute ```$_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['uname'];```, but this also does confuse me as I have read that POST and SESSION are both global so why does ```$logedInUsername = $_POST['uname']``` not work?